# running a task between equal interval of time in linux

Tags: linux

I have a Linux kernel(v3.0) with a rt patch.
how can i schedule a task to run every 2 or 3msec( i.e I want a program to execute for a given amount time with an interval of some millisecond)?
Thank you

Comment: Are you want this http://kvz.io/blog/2007/07/29/schedule-tasks-on-linux-using-crontab/ ?

Comment: @jkb using crontab we can only schedule for every min. I want something like that but I should be able to schedule every msec or micro sec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do it is to first create a timer with the required amount of time. and then to call the task( which is basically another program) every time the timer overflows. The program for the timer can be run in the background. the timer can be created and set using the timer_create() and timer_settime() respectively. A different program can be called from one program using fork() and execl(). The program can be run in the background using the daemon(). By using all these things we can create our own scheduler.